# how to add button array to layout in android?

Tags: java, android, layout, button

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add an array of buttons to a GridView in an Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775188/add-an-array-of-buttons-to-a-gridview-in-an-android-application)

I have Button List. I want to add these buttons in addition to current layout and also setOnclickListener to Button list. 
I can do how?

Comment: You will find similar at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775188/add-an-array-of-buttons-to-a-gridview-in-an-android-application

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
ArrayList<Button> buttonList = new ArrayList<Button>();
buttonList.add(new Button("b1"));
buttonList.add(new Button("b2"));
buttonList.add(new Button("b3")); ...

for(Button b : buttonList) {
   b.setOnclickListener(/*listener here*/);
}
```

Comment: simply as buttonList.add(new Button("b"));

Comment: how can I add buttons to layout not list

Comment: here is link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775188/add-an-array-of-buttons-to-a-gridview-in-an-android-application. and this list to tablerow and add it to the layout. Simple, TableRow t = new TableRow(); t.add(buttons); layout.add(t);