# Buttons not visible in gridview

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am new to android programming, and I am trying to get a button into an vertical scrolling grid. The buttons are not functional or visible. When I enable "Show layout bounds" in developer options, You see the gridview allocates space for the buttons::

[image]

My code is as follows:

layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:numColumns="4"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridLayout;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.fairphone.datatransparency.R;

import java.util.Iterator;

/**
 * Created by koen on 11/25/15.
 */
public class NewTimeLineFragment extends Fragment{
        public static final String ARG_OBJECT = "object";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // The last two arguments ensure LayoutParams are inflated
        // properly.
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.new_time_line_layout, container, false);
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        Button[] buttons = new Button[6];

        View.OnClickListener oclBtn = new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "GORGABAL", 5).show();
            }
        };

        for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
            buttons[i] = new Button(getActivity());
            buttons[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            buttons[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(oclBtn);
            buttons[i].setLayoutParams(lp);
            buttons[i].setText("GORGABAL");
        }

        GridView gridview;
        gridview = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        ArrayAdapter<Button> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Button>(this.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, buttons);

        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Log.d("Debug", "new_time_line fragment created");

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775188/add-an-array-of-buttons-to-a-gridview-in-an-android-application

Comment: Checkout the answer by cybercitizen1

Comment: That answer seems to omit the gridView and fragment completely, and use a tablelayout instead.